# Angular Multi select with output model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, multi-select

I am using the following Angular multi select dropdown

http://isteven.github.io/angular-multi-select/

```html
<div multi-select
        input-model="batch_timing.days"
        output-model="selectedData"
        button-label="acronym"
        item-label="acronym symbol name"
        tick-property="ticked"
        helper-elements="all none reset"
        required name="days">
</div>
```

When I create new form then it works correct.

But the problem comes when I want to edit the object and I already have some values in  `selectedData`

Ideally it should show only those values as pre-selected. But what is happening is, it makes `selectedData as empty` rather than bind from the scope, it actually writes to the scope.

How can I fix that?

Comment: can you provide a fiddle?